# Using one global filter pipe in Angular 10

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a set of items that I want to segment into different sections like section A, B, and C. When the user searches for the name, it updates the view of each section based on their search. This is my component HTML (`allItems = [{name:"someName", "items":Items[]}, {name:"someName2", "items":Items[]}, ...]`):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let itemSection of allItems ">
    <div class="section-title">{{itemSection.name}}</div>
    <ul class="item-grid">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of itemSection.items | itemFilter : searchText : searchType">
            <li class="item" (click)="addItem(item)">
                <div class="item-block">
                    <div class="bg-black" [ngClass]="isVisibleClass(item)">
                        <img class="item-img" [src]="item.img" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ng-container>
    </ul>
</ng-container>
```

As the number of `itemSection`'s grow, it applies multiple of the same filter pipe to each of those sections, making it laggy because of the constant filter on different items. I would rather apply one `itemFilter` pipe to all of items, add to it's respective `div` then render it:

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<ng-container *ngIf="items$ | async as items">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items | itemFilter : searchText : searchType">
        if item section == "a", put in div a
        else if item section == "b", put in div b
        ...
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
then render the contents of div a and b
```

I'm not sure how to make it less laggy with only applying the result of one filter pipe, but also segment the results into different sections. Any suggestions?